# Как сделать так: если кнопка нажата и не отпущена, действие повторяется

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как можно так сделать. Нужно максимально просто и понятно. Пишу игру на Android Studio.

Comment: onTouchEvent посмотрите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

      btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
              if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                  //нажата
              }
              if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                  //отпустили
              }
              return true;
          }
      });

      ...

    }
```

Comment: По непонятной причине не работает. Редактор Android Studio выделяет всё желтым цветом и отказывается нормально функционировать на эмуляторе.

Comment: @ilyacynep желтое это не страшно(студия предлагает упрощенный вариант), а вот функционировать должно, если бы вы привели лог ошибки и ваш код, я мог бы помочь

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Az1U3IFsmXUpMV41af_tX3-FDjp_P7Gl https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QVhLGZMQCsMC-p_3JsgH3KcHAhm7ZgpE  Вот код и ошибки

Comment: @ilyacynep в методе onCreate() уберите слово "Button" !!! перед btn = (Button) find....  А код из моего ответа вставьте в метод onCreate после этой строки

Comment: @ilyacynep я поправил ответ

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ldy83dkbon60ccm2sDlLrHbXh2w5h969         сделал

Comment: @ilyacynep и как работает?

Comment: Эмулятор просто говорит: приложение было остановлено, перепробовал кучу вариантов - безрезультатно.

Comment: @ilyacynep, очень плохая практика - использовать несколько разметок в одной активности. Думаю проблемы у вас из-за этого. Если надо менять макеты, то для этого используют фрагменты.

Comment: Получается, мне нужно создать новый фрагмент, и там прописать по вашей инструкции код?

Comment: Привет. Пишу после повторной пробы вашего кода.  Он заработал. Не знаю что ему до этого мешало, но он работает. Только не так как нужно, пока кнопка зажата он выполняет действие один раз. А нужно чтобы работает беспрерывно, пока не отпустят.

Comment: @ilyacynep да вы правы метод сработает один раз, для того что бы действие повторялось необходимо добавлять логики, например еще один поток как советует Вася Воронцов

Comment: Спасибо за ваш код. Я с помощью переменной и таймером смог сделать то что хотел, спасибо!